# jquery.blur() NOT in alert()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#htxtEmoney, #htxtPoint").keypress(function(e){
    var evt = window.event ? window.event : e;  //for compatibility
    var keyCode = evt.keyCode ? evt.keyCode : e.which;
    if (keyCode == 13 || keyCode == 27 || keyCode == 8) return ; // esc, enter
    if (48 <= keyCode && keyCode <= 57)
        return true; // number

    alert("You can write only Number.");

    this.focus();
    return false;
}).blur(function(e){
    Payments.onChangePoint(this);
});
```

Here is a code I wrote.

If the user input alphabet,  the `alert()` occur.

and then  the `blur()` function also occur.

But I want,  If an user input alphabet, the `alert()` occur and then the `blur()` function doesn't occur at that situation.

I mean the `blur()` function occur only the user click other control..

sorry about my poor English. thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alert shifts focus away from anything that has it, therefore automatically causing a blur. You cannot have an alert that will not cause a blur to occur.

A better solution to your problem would be to not cause an alert but rather to display a message next to or underneath your input. This will inform the user of the error and not lose focus on the input.

Comment: thank you. I will show msg-div under the input. I think it is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a variable that both functions have access to, outside of either, like

```
var izError = false;
```

and set it to true whenever you display the alert (`izError = true;`).

```
izError = false; //reset variable to false

....... //all your intervening code

izError = true;
alert("Don't do that.");
```

And then test for it before doing your onblur stuff:

```
if ( izError == false) {
  Payments.onChangePoint(this);
}
```